# area of surface generated revolving about the x axis stuck

Tags: calculus, area

Sorry, i'm sure this is an extremely simple problem, but stuck and extremely confused on how the answer is derived here

[image]

I'm fine with getting the deriviate, and using the formula to  find the area, but I just can't figure out how

we get sqrt(x/x-1) here

[image]

and how multiplying these two, becomes the sqrt(x)

[image]

step by step explanation would be amazing!! I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is the punctual radius of the jar.

$2 \pi f(x)$ is the slice perimeter of the jar.

$\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$. This is esoteric. Ask your book, this is equal to $\sqrt{1+({dy\over dx})^2}dx=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$. As you see, that is a little hypotenuse, for the length of the slice through the curve $f(x)$.

Hence the surface is the slice perimeter by its length, all sum:
$$
\int 2 \pi f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx
$$

so... which is your function??

Comment: I'm just confused on how the sinplication resulted in the sqrt(x/x-1) and how the two square roots below that results in the sqrt(x) does this make sense?

Comment: But.... which is the function you are revolving??